# Is there an API for Windows C# to allow printed text to stay at a specific location forever?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am writing a choose your own adventure game in C# console.

I want to keep (name) in a specific location for the console's lifespan. This is the part I am stuck on. After the code continues and dialogue is created eventually the console will scroll and (name) will no longer be showing.

Is there either an API I can use to keep (name) in it's desired location? Or is there a way I can stop scrolling from happening without having to place a code every 5 lines that refreshes the text on the console app?

```
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 0);
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Comment: I personally have not known an api that achieves your idea.

Comment: Actually, I suggest you implement the scrolling part yourself. You keep an array of lines, and each time pull the last `Console.WindowHeight` lines out, overlay the contents you desired over them, and print all of them over the existing text by `SetCursorPosition`.

Comment: Are you saying I should just override the text that is already on the screen to eliminate scrolling using SetCursorPosition?

I'm not understanding the pull the lines out part using WindowHeight.

Comment: Yes. As I don't know a way to keep the text at a fixed position for console, I think the best idea is to eliminate the scrolling. Use `Console.SetBufferSize` to set the buffer size the same as `Console.WindowWidth` and `WindowHeight` will disable the system scrolling. And if you want to have some scrolling feature, you can implement that yourself.

Comment: I think this solution will work perfectly, thank you for the idea!

Comment: If you are not using the built-in system scroll buffer (As it cannot keep content at fixed place I'm afraid you cannot use that), and if you still want the ability to see texts before, you can implement your own scroll buffer yourself by using an array of lines, and print a part of the array onto the screen based on your code logic. Anyway handling it yourself will get everything controllable by you.

Comment: I think you have to roll your own using the [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netframework-4.8).  [Console.MoveBufferArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.movebufferarea?view=netframework-4.8) is especially useful for this.  Also, (can't believe I'm linking to reddit), but [someone has suggested a bunch of C# curses-like libraries over there](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/8ad59h/console_graphic_library/dwy2ilb/).